# Why I can't import pyzmq on ubuntu 14.04 LTS？

Tags: python, pyzmq

I have installed zmq and pyzmq.But I can't import pyzmq.

```
>>> Successfully installed pyzmq
Cleaning up...
hepeng@hp:~$ python
enter code here
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pyzmq
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pyzmq
```

But I can import zmq.

```
>>> import zmq
>>>
```

So why?Thanks.

Comment: It could be an environment problem. Try closing your shell client and open it again.

Comment: Thx. But it didn't work……

Comment: What OS and distro/version are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04.03 LTS, pyzmq -15.1.0, zmq- 4.0.7.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`pyzmq` is the PyPI package installer name, but the actual root package is named and imported as `zmq`. This is just how some Python packages work; `PyYAML` is another example, being installed under the name `PyYAML`, but imported as `yaml`.

If you take a look at the [`zmq` docs](http://zguide.zeromq.org/py:all) or [`pyzmq` API](https://pyzmq.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/index.html), you'll notice all the Python examples `import` as `zmq`.